# Find the top 10 items in a JSON Dictionary based on an Int

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am looking to pull the top 10 instances of a JSON dictionary based on which has the highest Int's.

So for the example I'm showing, I'm looking for the top 10 ranked films based on their popularity ranking. I have posted an example of the dictionary below.

Part of the Dictionary:

```
{
"cast": [
{
  "id": 201,
  "character": "Praetor Shinzon",
  "original_title": "Star Trek: Nemesis",
  "overview": "En route to the honeymoon of William Riker to Deanna Troi on her home planet of Betazed, Captain Jean-Luc Picard and the crew of the U.S.S. Enterprise receives word from Starfleet that a coup has resulted in the installation of a new Romulan political leader, Shinzon, who claims to seek peace with the human-backed United Federation of Planets. Once in enemy territory, the captain and his crew make a startling discovery: Shinzon is human, a slave from the Romulan sister planet of Remus, and has a secret, shocking relationship to Picard himself.",
  "vote_count": 643,
  "video": false,
  "media_type": "movie",
  "release_date": "2002-12-13",
  "vote_average": 6.2,
  "title": "Star Trek: Nemesis",
  "popularity": 7.61,
  "original_language": "en",
  "genre_ids": [
    28,
    12,
    878,
    53
  ],
  "backdrop_path": "/1SLR0LqYPU3ahXyPK9RZISjI3B7.jpg",
  "adult": false,
  "poster_path": "/n4TpLWPi062AofIq4kwmaPNBSvA.jpg",
  "credit_id": "52fe4226c3a36847f8007d05"
},
{
  "id": 855,
  "character": "Spec. Lance Twombly",
  "original_title": "Black Hawk Down",
  "overview": "When U.S. Rangers and an elite Delta Force team attempt to kidnap two underlings of a Somali warlord, their Black Hawk helicopters are shot down, and the Americans suffer heavy casualties, facing intense fighting from the militia on the ground.",
  "vote_count": 2540,
  "video": false,
  "media_type": "movie",
  "release_date": "2001-12-28",
  "vote_average": 7.3,
  "title": "Black Hawk Down",
  "popularity": 11.504,
  "original_language": "en",
  "genre_ids": [
    28,
    36,
    10752
  ],
  "backdrop_path": "/7u2p0VxnhVMHzfSnxiwz5iD3EP7.jpg",
  "adult": false,
  "poster_path": "/yUzQ4r3q1Dy0bUAkMvUIwf0rPpR.jpg",
  "credit_id": "52fe4282c3a36847f80248ef"
},
```

From this dictionary what would be the right code used to pull the Top 10 film's based on their popularity ranking?

Here is some of the code:

```
 struct Cast: Codable {
    let title: String
    let character: String
    let poster_path: String?
    let id: Int
    let popularity: Double?
}

var filmCredits = [Cast]()
```

First issue I'm having is when I use `return 10` to return 10 results:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

I receive the error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` when calling the indexPath in my `cellForItemAt` func.

Here is the JSON Decoder Func:

```
func loadFilms() {

    let apiKey = ""
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/\(id)/combined_credits?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US")
    let request = URLRequest(
        url: url! as URL,
        cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10 )

    let session = URLSession (
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        delegate: nil,
        delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
    )

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let films = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Credits.self, from: data)
                self.filmCredits = films.cast!
                self.topCollection.reloadData()

            }

        }

        self.topCollection.reloadData()

    })


    task.resume()

}
```

What I'm most unsure of is how to pull only the Top 10 ranked films. Would I use something similar to `filter` or `map`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declare `cast` in `Credits` non-optional

```
struct Credits: Decodable {
    let cast: [Cast]
}
```

Sort the array descending by `popularity` when assigning to the data source array

```
self.filmCredits = films.cast.sorted{($0.popularity ?? 0.0) > $1.popularity ?? 0.0})
```

Don't hard-code `numberOfItemsInSection`. The crash occurs if the `cast` array contains less than 10 items. Add a condition that 10 items are displayed if the number of items is greater than 10  otherwise the number of items in the array.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberOfCredits = filmCredits.count
    return numberOfCredits > 10 ? 10 : numberOfCredits
}
```

And `catch` a possible error and reload the collection view on the main thread

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let films = try JSONDecoder().decode(Credits.self, from: data)
        self.filmCredits = films.cast.sorted{($0.popularity ?? 0.0) > $1.popularity ?? 0.0})
    } catch{ print(error) }
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.topCollection.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @JSharpp, Along with the above code please don't forget to run self.topCollection.reloadData() inside DispatchQueue.main.async{ } in the function session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:(_).

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
filmCredits.sort{ $0.popularity > $1.popularity}
```

---

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return min(filmCredits.count,10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write `return 10` in the delegate method `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int`. You cannot be sure you will always have exactly 10 results. If you have less than 10, your app crashes in `itemForRowAt`.

NB: you mention `cellForRowAt` which is for `UITableView`s but your code shows `collectionView`, be sure you are using the right delegate methods.

Then fill up an array that contains the popularity info, sort it in decreasing order and you will be good to go and use something like [Sh_Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan) mentioned:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return min(filmCredits.count,10)
    }
```